# Java how to update String of Text file

Tags: java, file

I want to update content of my Text file that is created using Scanner class of Java. Each line of text file consists of 4 strings. I want to update 2 strings of every line whenever user updates values. I've tried different codes but nothing is working. Kindly help me to update my values. what should be solution?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class File2
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\f");
        System.out.println("Enter Material");
        String material=obj.next();
        String color="Tendra Black";
        System.out.println("Enter quantity");
        String quantity=obj.next();
        System.out.println("Enter roll");
        String roll=obj.next();
        Scanner fileIn = null;

        try
        {
            fileIn = new Scanner (new FileInputStream("Stock.txt"));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException f)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File not found. Please specify coreect location.");
        }

        if(fileIn.hasNext())
        {
            while(fileIn.hasNext())
            {
                File log= new File("Stock.txt");

                String details = fileIn.nextLine();     
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(details,"-"); 
                String materialAvailable=null;
                String colorAvailable=null;
                String quantityAvailable=null;
                String rollAvailable=null;

                while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    materialAvailable=tokenizer.nextToken();
                    colorAvailable=tokenizer.nextToken();
                    quantityAvailable=tokenizer.nextToken();
                    rollAvailable=tokenizer.nextToken();

                    if((colorAvailable.equalsIgnoreCase(color)))
                    {

                        int val1Q=Integer.parseInt(quantityAvailable);
                        int val2Q=Integer.parseInt(quantity);
                        int val1R=Integer.parseInt(rollAvailable);
                        int val2R=Integer.parseInt(roll);
                        int quanF=val1Q+val2Q;
                        int rollF=val1R+val2R;
                        //quantityAvailable=Integer.toString(quanF);
                        //rollAvailable=Integer.toString(rollF);//file readTill
                        details=details.replaceAll(quantityAvailable,Integer.toString(quanF));
                        details=details.replaceAll(rollAvailable,Integer.toString(rollF));

                    }
                    try{
                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(log);
                        fw.write(details);
                        fw.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if you only have a total of 4 lines to write to the file then simply overwrite the existing file

Comment: I've almost 15 lines to whom I want to update. During execution one line should be changed and rest of lines should be same as before. I'm using print writer to write files. Can you tell me that how I can overwrite text file?

Comment: All I need is to update my text file. If you can help me with overwrite method then I can go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to open the file to overwrite instead of append, use a FileOutputStream and set the append value to false, like this

```
try{
    FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream(log, false);
    fw.write(details);
    fw.close();
}
```

Comment: First of all I read 15 lines from the file and then search for specific line. after finding that line using specific string of that line I want to update value of that string..for update now i need to write that new value again to file..so my query in a single line is that I want to read and then write same file in one program.

Comment: so then create an array list of strings where string at index 0 is line 1 in the file and so on. Then search that list of arraylists for the line you want to update, update it, then loop the arraylist and write the contents of the arraylist back to the file.

Comment: Seems good. I'll use arrays. Just one last thing that I need to know is that how I can flush previous data of file and overwrite with new data?PrintWriter is not working to overwrite file.